# Regressing state-level coefficient on state-level law

Tags: stata

I have the following.

```
county  state   employment  county_shock  state_law
 1        NY      70         3              10
 2        NY      80         4              10
 4        IL      100        2               5
 7        IL      60         9               5
 3        TX      90         8               2
```

I ran the regression for all counties:

```
regress employment county_shock
```

But now I am curious about the state-level law on the degree to which county_shock affects employment.

Not sure adding interaction term achieves this.

But what I am trying to do is the following:

Run

```
regress employment county_shock
```

for "each state"

Then I will have coefficient for county_shock for each state. I could get those coefficients by "_b"

Then, regress those coefficients on state-level law.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I thought at first:

The initial model is `y = b0 + b1*x + u`, where `x` is `county_shock` for short. You mean `b1` is a function of `z`, which is `state_law`. For this you can regress `y` on `x`, `z` and `x*z`. (Here you want to let the intercept different across `state` as well. The model without `z` looks strange because it means that the intercept is the same for all states.)

Now, let the model with interaction be `y = c0 + c1*x + c2*z + c3*x*z + u`. This is written as `y = (c0 + c2*z) + (c1+c3*z)*x + u`. Thus, `c3` is the coefficient you want.

In Stata,

```
reg employment c.county_shock##c.state_law
```

-

After reading the second part of your question, I am not sure if this is what you want.